# Writing a JEST Test for a Function that Contains a Promise and setTimeout

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest

I'm trying to write a test for a Lightning Web Component that fires a custom event, which causes a function to execute in the component.

The code for the test is below:

```
        it('make recurring button is disabled if imported gift is loaded into the form', async () => {
        const formApp = setupForBatchMode(
            {
                giftBatchId: 'DUMMY_BATCH_ID',
                gifts: [
                    {
                        fields: {
                            Id : 'DUMMY_RECORD_ID'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                totals: { TOTAL: 1 }
        });
        await flushPromises();

        const geBatchTable = shadowQuerySelector(formApp, 'c-ge-batch-gift-entry-table');
        expect(geBatchTable).toBeTruthy();

        const loadDataEvent = new CustomEvent('loaddata', {
            detail: {
                id : 'DUMMY_GIFT_ID'
            }
        });

        runWithFakeTimer(async () => {
            geBatchTable.dispatchEvent(loadDataEvent);
            await flushPromises();
        });

        const geFormRenderer = shadowQuerySelector(formApp, 'c-ge-form-renderer');
        expect(geFormRenderer).toBeTruthy();

        const makeRecurringButton = geFormRenderer.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('[data-id="recurringButton"]');
        expect(makeRecurringButton).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

The `handleLoadData()` function I am testing:

```
handleLoadData(event) {
    try {
        this.isFormRendering = true;
        new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            setTimeout(()=> {
                console.log('event', event.detail);
                const giftId = event.detail.id;
                console.log(this.giftBatch.state());
                console.log('gift id', giftId);
                let foundGift = {};
                foundGift = this.giftBatch.findGiftBy(giftId);
                this.gift = new Gift(foundGift.state());
                this.giftInView = this.gift.state();
                this.openedGiftDonationId = this.gift.donationId();
                if (this.isFormCollapsed) {
                    this.isFormCollapsed = false;
                }
                fireEvent(this, 'resetElevateWidget', {});
                resolve();
            }, 100);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.isFormRendering = false;
        });
    } catch(error) {
        handleError(error);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the function returns a `Promise` which contains a `setTimeout()`. The `dispatchEvent()` is called on line 281 in the test which I have wrapped in a `runWithFaketimers()` function to try to get the timers to advance so that the `handleLoadData()` function and the test will resolve:

```
const runWithFakeTimer = (someFn) => {
jest.useFakeTimers();
someFn();
jest.runAllTimers();
jest.useRealTimers();
```

}

When this test executes, it instead runs indefinitely due to what I assume to be the `Promise` not resolving or the timer not advancing. What am I missing here regarding how I should set up this test to either correctly resolve the Promise or advance the timer so that the test can complete successfully?

Note: If helpful, the logic used in the `flushPromises()` function is below:

```
global.flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,0));
```

Comment: What's the reason for the setTimeout in handleLoadData to begin with?